# How to fix this exception

Tags: hibernate

I'm getting exception
plz help me how to solve this i mapped all the data correctly and configuration also i did but it still showing exception.

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager cannot be cast to org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProviderInjector
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.createReflectionManager(Configuration.java:2589)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.createReflectionManager(Configuration.java:2584)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:295)
```

Comment: There are two problems, as I can see, 1 minor: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder ..and one graver: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-javareflectionmanager-cannot-be-cast-to-metadataproviderinjector/

Comment: Thank you sir,now its working